# Using 'zechus avos' in this world

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, reward-punishment

On the one hand [*zechus avos*](http://www.ybm.org.il/upload/lehela/5773/vaethanan.pdf) has an affect in this world. On the other hand [*schar mitzvah be'hay almah leika*](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=39b&format=pdf) (the reward of a mitzvah is not given in this world.)

How do these two idea's work? They seem to contradict each other.

Comment: Perhaps this question is no longer relevant, as there's no more zechus avos left (Shabbos 55)